# Email Sent By Perl (Net::SMTP) Script Dropped Silently by Gmail

Tags: perl, email, gmail, google-workspace

I have a Perl script that sends simple HTML emails to users with status updates and a link to more information.  I'm creating mail with Net::SMTP and sending mail using smtp-relay.gmail.com.  It has been working great for years.

In the last month, the emails stopped appearing - just gone with no errors and not in SPAM.  Hours of troubleshooting later, I've narrowed the problem down to Gmail silently dropping emails that contain my specific URL.

```
http://DOMAIN/cgi-bin/requests/single_request.pl?requestid=111111
```

I changed one character and POOF! working again.

```
http://DOMAIN/cgi-bin/requests/single-request.pl?requestid=111111
```

I know this is a vague question, but what is going on?  The workaround is fine, but I sure didn't learn anything about the root cause.

```
#!c:\strawberry\perl\bin -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SMTP;
use Net::Config;

# use this function to send email
#
# example:
#
# send_mail("RECIPIENT\@DOMAIN", "SUBJECT HERE", "BODY HERE");


sub send_mail{
my $recipient = shift;
my $subject = shift;
my $body = shift;

# connect to an SMTP server
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new("smtp-relay.gmail.com", Debug => 0, Timeout => 30, Hello => 'REDACTED') or die "SMTP Connection Failed: smtp-relay.gmail.com"; 

# sender's address here
$smtp->mail('REDACTED');

# recipient"s address
$smtp->to($recipient);

# Start the mail
$smtp->data(); 

# Send the header.
$smtp->datasend("MIME-Version: 1.0\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\" \n");
$smtp->datasend("To: $recipient . \n");
$smtp->datasend("From: REDACTED\n");
$smtp->datasend("Reply-to: REDACTED\n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: $subject \n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");

# Send the body.
$smtp->datasend($body);

# Finish sending the mail
$smtp->dataend(); 

# Close the SMTP connection
$smtp->quit(); 
}
1;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is obviously not related to Perl  or programming at all but to the content of the delivered mail. It was probably considered a phishing mail because of the syntax of the included URL.

Comment: I agree with Steffen. If you're a legitimate Google customer and you're allowed to use their mail relay, just write them and explain the situation. You might be able to go with their _abuse_ address. Typically that's used to report abuse, but have a situation where your legitimate stuff is falsely classified as something abuse-related. Let them know. Ask them nicely. They will probably fix it.

Comment: Well ok.  I wasn't sure if it was some kind of bad coding practice that I wasn't aware of.   Maybe it's ok for the correct answer to be "you did everything correctly".

Comment: For me, this was a useful example of a complete/working script!!